# How do I model a bottle case like this?

Tags: modeling

So, I'm not that new to blender or 3d modeling at all, but I've been cracking my head on this one.

I need to create a high resolution 3d model with a clean geometry of the following object:

[image]

This is a bottle case (used to keep beer cold on hot days).

I've tried many different methods, but I always end up with weird geometry and subsurf gives me weird results (too much sharpness on some places or weird artifacts).

I know this is a rather simple piece, but I think I'm working too much and my brain has just shut down :P

Thank you for your time!

Comment: ...... Get a cylinder. Get some other cylinders. Use the other cylinders to Boolean the original cylinder. Ta data, you got this object.

Comment: @Bradman175 As far as this is tutorial request and not too good question you shouldn't answer with clearly wrong answer. "high resolution 3d model with a clean geometry" - you can't do this with Boolen.

Comment: @LukeD break the high resolution object into pieces? And then Boolean?

Comment: @LukeD - he's not so wrong after all. The object itself can be easily broken down into primitives and that's always the best way to start from. You then go from low-poly to high-poly by adding loopcuts (for the edges and of course to get an evenly subdivided object) and use a subdiv or multi-res modifier on top of it.

Comment: @metaphor_set and you call it "clean"? After Boolen? Ngons, tris, it's total mess not clean.

Comment: @Bradman175 Please make an answer with your method, I'm really curious about this "clean" geometry after boolen. Maybe I'll start using it.

Comment: @LukeD - I've done a lot more complicated stuff with boolean. No tris, no ngons - so yeah, I call it clean. If you are working with primitives it all comes down to proper planing, like "having the loop cuts at the right places" and such.

Comment: @metaphor_set I'm waiting for an answer then, it's always something new to learn.

Comment: @LukeD - it's basic stuff. Nothing new to learn here. You can also do it easily by yourself. Like I said, loopcuts at the right places, then you can either use boolean or just slide the vertices. That's all.

Comment: @metaphor_set we shouldn't talk in comments. Just make simple answer. I don't use boolen at all, so this case presented by OP is very interesting for me.

Comment: I have to return home to try this. It will take a while.

Comment: I really can't see why my question has been downvoted. it's clearly not that trivial or straightforward to produce this object (as you can see in the argument this caused in this comment section). if it's that simple/tutorial-like and not worthy of questioning, I would really appreciate if some of those guys would pm me the solution.
btw, boolean method gives terribly awful results after subdividing/beveling

Answer (score 4):

After much fiddling around, I came to an acceptable solution, as follows:

[image]
1) Start with a cylinder

[image]
2) Use Inset and delete to poke a hole in the top-most face

[image]
3) Using the Knife tool, make two cuts conecting the vertices

[image]
4) Add edge loops in the center (ctrl+R + scroll)

[image]
5) Using proportional editing in *Project 2d and Sphere shape* (important!) drag the middle vertices down (use f6 to fine tune the proportional size and translation)

[image]
6) Add loops to the side of the tris (to avoid problems when subdividing)

[image]
7) Finish as needed. Here I used Solidify, Bevel and Subdiv modifiers. Also made a hole in the middle for that crease and use the Bevel tool to better define some edges (like in the flat segments in the top)

Now, I know this seems easy to many, but it really took me a while to realize I could use the Project 2d mode in proportional editing and to correctly cut and model's the top part this way.

I hope this helps somebody with similar problems.

ps: sorry for the crappy answer, I'm really not used to give this kind of answer nor I do have the recording tools for that.